Simple clustered scan on table with 700 rows taking considerable time

I have this table, which has just 700 rows. Doing select * on takes a considerable amount of time. More than a minute to fetch first 40 rows, 2 minutes to fetch 80 rows likewise. I tried updating statistics, added primary key column, there is no blocking query running in parallel. But I see no performance improvement.
Only select on this table is slow. Could it be due to XML based column which has query plan and sql_command column which has SQL command executed? Should I check for other things?
How can I improve the performance of this query?

Did you select only a few columns and check whether this makes a difference? Or hit Ctrl + L and see if missing indexes or similar issues will be found.

Yes, removing execution plan, fetched rows really fast like 09 seconds

Hard to tell what exactly causes the performance issue without knowing the data which appears in this column. There are some similar questions, for example Bad XML performance. Did you see them and check if the answers help?

How mcuh data is it? You have some potentially large columns: the nvarchar(max) and xml could be up to 2GB each.

Why do you need to return the XML for all 700 rows?

Try running SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(sql_command_for_head_blocker)) FROM YourTable and SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(execution_plan)) FROM YourTable to see how much data is coming back from these columns. That might explain the time required.

The native XML is not the XML you see but will be stored within hidden tables. Running a select * will force the engine to build the readable XML which can be huge in your case. The time is not while reading, but while creating the presentable/human-readable result set.
